# How to save an image received through network in java

Tags: java, networking, image-processing

image is successfully received at the server side and I can display it on label
but my ***Problem* is how to save that image**

I have used

> JFileChooser.showSaveDialog()

I tried printstream. I can save the file but whenever I opened the file in image viewer it is showing as *this type of file is cant be opened*

---

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(sock.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("Image received!!!!"); 

JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int i=fc.showSaveDialog(null);
if( i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {                

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fc.getSelectedFile());

    // ImageIO.write(bimg,"JPG",fc.getInputStream());
    ps.print( img);
    ps.close();
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img)); //image is successfully displaying on the label
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the "object" representation of the image, only if your load it through `PrintStream` would you have a chance of seeing it again.

Try using something like...

```
ImageIO.write(img,"JPG",fc.getSelectedFile());
```

instead

Comment: Well, that makes a nice change